# cakephp: single code line or block to allow all authenticated users to action

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, acl, cakephp-2.1

I am using cake 2.x

I am also using Auth and Acl Component.

I want to allow a single action to all the logged in users.

But this results in me writing this code several times and then running the initDB.

```
public function initDB() {
    $group = $this->User->Group;
    //Allow ADMINISTRATORS to everything
    $group->id = ADMINISTRATORS;
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

    //allow SALES_MANAGERS to upload SOW file at `products`
    $group->id = SALES_MANAGERS;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Pages');


    //allow SOLUTION_ARCHITECTS to only add and edit on posts and widgets
    $group->id = SOLUTION_ARCHITECTS;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Pages');

    //allow IMPLEMENTATION_MANAGERS to only add and edit on posts and widgets
    $group->id = IMPLEMENTATION_MANAGERS;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Pages');

    //we add an exit to avoid an ugly "missing views" error message
    echo "all done";
    exit;
}
```

As you noticed I needed to allow Pages to all the various groups.

I prefer a simple way similar to Auth->allow that allows certain actions always to ALL logged in users.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

THis is my workaround. Any better solution?

```
public function initDB() {
    $group = $this->User->Group;

  ... // didn't want to repeat this part which  is same as above.

  // we allow all groups the following actions
    $onlyForLoggedInUsers = array(
        'controllers/Users/logout',
        'controllers/Pages',
    );
    $this->_allowAllGroupsThisAction($onlyForLoggedInUsers);

    //we add an exit to avoid an ugly "missing views" error message
    echo "all done";
    exit;
}

protected function _allowAllGroupsThisAction($actions) {
    $groups = array(SALES_MANAGERS, SOLUTION_ARCHITECTS, IMPLEMENTATION_MANAGERS);
    $actions = (array)$actions;
    $group = $this->User->Group;
    foreach ($groups as $id) {
        $group->id = $id;
        foreach($actions as $action) {
            $this->Acl->allow($group, $action);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create your groups to be hierarchical you can.  create a group structure that actsAs Tree, and structure your data like so:

- Users

  - Administrators
  - Managers

    - Sales Managers
    - Implementation Managers
  - Developers

    - Solution Architects

with this structure, any permission assigned to a parent ARO will be inherited by all descendants.  instructions on how to set configure the parent behavior can be found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#acts-as-a-requester

Comment: So I need to follow this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html and add in parent, lft, rgt columns to the groups table. Also, add in the TreeBehavior to the Group model. Is there any other major changes I need to do?